# GLM summary shows no significant difference for variable but difference can be seen in plot

Tags: multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, data-visualization

I am doing a multiple regression to predict average sizes of fish between areas protected from fishing and areas open to fishing. The model also takes into account habitat parameters which are the other variables (log.comp2 + rugosity). This model was the best according to AIC. log(size) transformation was used to normalize data.

`mtar <- glm(log(size) ~ log.comp2 + rugosity + protection + log.comp2:protection, tar, family = "gaussian")`

The output for  `summary(mtar)` shows no significant difference for protection:

```
                             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                  3.370952   0.022943 146.928  < 2e-16 ***
log.comp2                    0.132060   0.028386   4.652 3.48e-06 ***
rugosity                    -0.108574   0.008749 -12.410  < 2e-16 ***
protectionNo-take           -0.005873   0.023595  -0.249  0.80346    
log.comp2:protectionNo-take  0.125109   0.039544   3.164  0.00158 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 0.05726864)

    Null deviance: 139.63  on 2192  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 125.30  on 2188  degrees of freedom
AIC: -41.526
```

but the graph shows clear differences:
[image]

How can I interpret this?

Comment: I see no inconsistency between the output and the graphs.  What specific aspect of these two bothers you?

Comment: Given the present and significant interaction, the main effect of protection is probably not worth interrogation